# Change peculiar symbols into Danish symbols/letters

Tags: vba, str-replace, symbols

I am importing a range of CSV-files from a fixed folder. There are some letters that VBA cannot recognize and transforms them into peculiar symbols. For example, it changes all the "æ's" in the CSV's to "µ's", so I have to change them back. I have solved some of the issues buy using the following sentences:

```
TempSheet2.Cells.Replace "µ", "æ", xlPart, , False
TempSheet2.Cells.Replace "°", "ø", xlPart, , False
```

However, some of the symbols (like sigma, ╪ and ┼) VB cannot recognize.

I want the following corrections to be done:

Sigma should be changed back to "å".
╪ should be changed back to "Ø"
┼ should be changed back to "Å".

I tried to use

```
Option Compare Text
```

statement to solve the two bottom replacements but it didn't work.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code for "╪ should be changed back to "Ø"":

```
ActiveCell.Cells.Replace ChrW(9578), Chr(216) 'Sorry my mistake
```

Where the ASCII codes are for example here:

http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=116:ascii-code-extended-ascii-characters-8-bit-system-and-ansi-code&catid=78&Itemid=474

or by code:

```
test = AscW(ActiveCell)
```

Asc and AscW
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/zew1e4wc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Chr and ChrW
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: I've tried looking the symbols up in ASCII, ASCI and HEX lists, but they don't match. When I insert chr(165) in Excel, it comes out as ¥ and not as ╪.